# -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Tags: ios, objective-c

Do I need to add anything else in info.plist?

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb232259140641364</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>232259140641364</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>lodore</string>


   <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is really confusing. What is that error message doing in there? Don't just dump text, explain it!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've got the same problem, I've added the string to the Info.plist and tried -canOpenUrl but got the same error message.

Comment: @TomSpee where you able to solve this? I got the same error

Comment: @Spark For Facebook this works for me, my comment was about a different app that had a different scheme then I thought. For Facebook you should just follow their quick-start example, just implemented it this week and works fine.

Comment: Got it! Even though I get this error, I am able to log in using facebook into my app. Weird